# Objective C - problem with passing an object name though method parameter when initializing object

Tags: objective-c, object, methods, parameters

I am very new to Objective C and am trying to create a method for initializing an object (button object to be more precise) with only one line of code...  My method declaration is...

```
- (void)buttonDeclaration: (UIButton *)mButton :(int)xloc :(int)yloc :(int)bWidth :(int)bHeight 
                         : (NSString *)sImage :(UIViewController *)mView :(SEL)mSelector
{
  mButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [self buttonSetxy:mButton :xloc :yloc :bWidth :bHeight];
  [mButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  [mView.view addSubview:mButton];
}
```

My method call is...

```
[...buttonDeclaration:newButton :40 :65 :80 :65...]
```

but when I try to add

```
[newButton setHidden:FALSE];
```

after my call to the method it does nothing.  I'm not sure what the proper term is, but the object name should be newButton not mButton.  Does this make sense and how do I accomplish this?

Comment: what does the buttonSetxy method do??? are you setting up the frame properly?

Comment: buttonSetxy is merely another custom method that just changes the coordinates of my buttons.  Again, for single line coding in my main viewcontroller.

Comment: can u post the code for buttonSetxy? Cz if u wont be setting up the frame of the btn then it wudnt get added.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the way methods are declared in objective c is different.

When you declare method with multiple arguments then it should be like this.

> - (void) myMethod : (int)firstNum secondArgument:(int)secondNum

so ur method will be declared like

> - (void)buttonDeclaration: (UIButton *)mButton xPosition:(int)xloc yPosition:(int)yloc Width:(int)bWidth height:(int)bHeight imageName: (NSString *)sImage myView:(UIViewController *)mView selector:(SEL)mSelector

Now you will be calling this method by

> [self buttonDeclaration : myBtn xPosition : 5 yPosition : 10 width : 5 height : 10 and so on.......]

and if you want to hide your button, just write

> myBtn.hidden = YES;

Comment: This merely changes the names but won't have any other effect. I agree that using unnamed arguments is a bad thing, though.